# How to combine the GOOGLEFINANCE formula with the INDEX

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I used the following GOOGLEFINANCE function to import market data straight into Google Sheets and it works:

`=GOOGLEFINANCE("INDEXDJX:.DJI"; "high"; $A$1)`

But I only want to get the high price, without the cells that indicate the date and the headers. Tried this formula but didn't work:

`=index(GOOGLEFINANCE("INDEXDJX:.DJI"; "high";$A$1),2,2)`

Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `index` + `flatten` and get the `4`th element:

```
=index(flatten(GOOGLEFINANCE("INDEXDJX:.DJI", "high", $A$1)),4)
```

[image: example]